# Wagtail ignoring settings such as ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, settings, gunicorn, wagtail

I'm running nginx, gunicorn and wagtail on Ubuntu 16.04. I am not using virtualenv. Both nginx and gunicorn seem to work just fine but when I go to my domain in a browser (let's say myweb.com) I get a disallowed host error.

This seems like a simple problem but I have already added myweb.com as an allowed host in base.py like so: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myweb.com']. It even says in the request information that myweb.com is an allowed host in the settings file but it seems like wagtail is just ignoring that. I also tried turning debug off in the dev settings but it still showed me the debug screen.

Edit: The specific error message is (with myweb.com instead of the actual domain):

```
DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'myweb.com'. You may need to add 'myweb.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://myweb.com/

Django Version:     1.11.5

Exception Type:     DisallowedHost

Exception Value:    Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'myweb.com'. You may need to add 'myweb.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 113

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3

Python Version:     3.5.2

Python Path:    

['/home/fixgoats/myweb-root',
'/usr/local/bin',
'/usr/lib/python35.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.5',
'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
138.             response = self.process_request(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
57.         host = request.get_host()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/http/request.py" in get_host
113.             raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'myweb.com'. You may need to add 'myweb.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Information:

USER [unable to retrieve the current user]

GET     No GET data

POST    No POST data

FILES   No FILES data

Settings     Using settings module myweb.settings.dev

ALLOWED_HOSTS 'myweb.com'
```

There was quite a bit more information on the page but I think this is everything that might be relevant to the problem

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what error you're getting specifically

Comment: @TheCog I've added some information about the error

Comment: try ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*], only to test ALLOWED_HOSTS. if it works try ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.myweb.com', 'myweb.com']

Comment: It works now, both ['*'] and ['myweb.com']. But I also restarted the server in the meantime so that may have had more to do with it. I guess I can't say for certain what fixed it, perhaps gunicorn needed to be restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunicorn needed to be restarted. I don't know if it's supposed to work like this but on my setup it seems like Gunicorn always needs to be restarted to detect changes made to the project files.